# How to apply a "buy two products together and save some money" block on product page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog-price-rules, shopping-cart-price-rules

[image: my rule image]

I am trying to make a block which shows two products in it with a rule that if a customer bought these two products he will save some amount of money.
I want to do something like this, Can any one let me know how can i do that.
I tried reading the content for shopping cart price rule and catalog price rule but didn't get how to make this type of product rule.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same can be achieve using aheadworks frequently bought together extension: http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/frequently-bought-together.html

Comment: Thanks for the extension I want exactly this, but this is not free of cost so i cannot use this.
Is there any other way to achieve this by making some module or block programmatically. I need to do this by tomorrow.Can any one please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Well I achieve this kind of functionality without use of any extensions.

Comment: Thats good.
You can add solution here and add it as a answer :)

Comment: Well it is not complete yet, just one more thing to do and then I will add the answer over here. Thanks.

Comment: @Waseem did you ever solve this?

Comment: @DavidManners yeah I solve this. but not sure its an appropriate way. because the rule I set is particularly for the two products only. For the other products set I have to define the rule again.

Comment: @Waseem feel free to share you solution as an answer, it may help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am here to share my answer for this approach of adding products together. Well May be its not the best way but it works for me.

**First Step**

Firstly I created a new `attribute` say `Frequently Bought` and add it in the `attribute set` of `products`

**Second Step**

Then I set the value of the attribute created for products which I want to add together in the cart.

*Note* The value should be same for attribute.

**Third Step**

Then I filter the product according to my new attribute, which obviously only gives me two products.

And then I used an ajax to add both to cart.

**Final Step**

Then simply create the rule for the products.

That's all. May be it help someone. Thanks for inspiring me to share an answer.

Comment: may i see your demo?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a little work on your individual product page theme.  The functionality is already there in magento, you just have to make it look like it.

You can start by going into each product and setting up your upsell/cross-sell individually.  This gives you the most control, but takes the longest amount of time.  For more broad rules, look into the rule based product relations you mentioned in your question.

You can then create the discounts by setting up shopping cart price rules.

After that, all you need to do is edit your theme.  You can do this in either related.phtml or upsell.phtml, (depending on how you setup your relations rules).

These themes are located in *app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/catalog/product/list/*

Comment: Thanks for the the answer @ryan I had done this thanks again.